# Slow 'solve_ivp' speed when implemented inside an objective function of 'shgo'

Tags: performance, optimization, scipy, solver, scipy-optimize

I'm using `scipy.optimize.shgo` (*`shgo(objective_function, bounds=bnds, iters=2, minimizer_kwargs={'method':'SLSQP', 'ftol':1e-3})`*), and inside the objective_function, `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` is used with '`RK23`' method.

When I ran `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` outside the objective function, it took about 6 mins. However, when I ran the same code inside the objective_function, it took much longer than that.

I tried to track the `t` by printing `t` while running, and I found that delta t (from `solve_ivp`) is much smaller when it was run inside the objective_function (0.00000001 < 0.001), and I guess that's why it takes longer.

Would this be intrinsic/unavoidable issue? Or, how would I be able to make it faster?